# Check a table row cell for contents

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use jQuery to check if the 2nd cell in each table row of a table contains any text, if the 2nd cell doesn't contain any text then set the table row to display: none;

Whats the best way to go about this?

HTML:

```
<table id="results">
  <tr>
    <td>Results</td>
    <td>1000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td></td> <!-- This cell is empty so hide row -->
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Time/Date</td>
    <td>14:03 22/01/12</td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [:empty selector](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/):

```
$('table tr').has('td:empty:nth-child(2)').hide()
```

Comment: Huh, I somehow didn't know about `has`. Useful! This avoids the anonymous function or extra DOM traversing in all the other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table tr').each(function() {
    if(!$(this).find('td').eq(1).html().length) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

This will loop through each `tr`, find the second element using [`$.eq(1)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) (arrays start from zero) and see if it contains anything using `$.html().length`. If it's empty, it hides the `tr` with `$(this).hide()`.

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution, make use of `:empty` selector

```
$("#results tr").find('td:eq(1):empty').parent().hide();
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/GHg7f/2/

Comment: I tested it, it works fine here.

Note that it is not necessary to null-check `empty_td` - jQuery will return an empty collection if there are no matching elements.