# Hide table row if one of its columns is empty using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, row, cells

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [hide row if it contains empty columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978812/hide-row-if-it-contains-empty-columns)

Can the row containing empty cell in this table be hidden using CSS.. I have tried jQuery and its not working right now..
this is what I used and it doesn't do anything!

```
$('.EventDetail tr').each(function(){      
    if ($('td:empty',this).length > 0))
    $(this).hide();
});
```

There ain't nothing wrong with this piece of jQuery, is there? I would like to see if we can do `display:none` for the selected row? Is it something achievable using CSS?

```
<table cellpadding="10" class ="EventDetail">
    <tr>
        <td class="TableFields"><em>Who Should Enroll?:</em></td>
        <td>Everyone 18 and older who would like to attend</td>
    </tr>       
    <tr>
        <td class="TableFields"><em>Handicapped Access:</em></td>
        <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="TableFields"><em>Parking Notes:</em></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="TableFields"><em>Instructor:</em></td>
        <td>John Filler</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Flagged. You asked this same question 4 hours ago... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978812

Comment: I've voted to close this as a duplicate. If you want to do this just in CSS then why did you tag the question with jQuery and JavaScript? Why include a jQuery code sample? You should've rephrased the whole question to say "Is it possible to hide these rows with _just_ CSS".

Comment: You start by not being sarcastic because beggars cannot be choosers. You then edit your question to improve it and work through the comment system to get additional help.

Comment: You are asking a community for help, which is what we are. If anstosa was mistaken in flagging your post then you should clarify why it is not a repeat or edit it to help people understand what you are achieving. Instead you give a sarcastic response.

Comment: And you've asked 31 questions and answered none. For one so interested helping others freely you sure haven't taken the time to give back.

Comment: @mrtsherman Apologies! I shouldn't have been sarcastic! I will try to be careful with the way I ask questions. About not answering questions in the community, I am kinda new to the community.I will see how i can contribute!

Comment: @Anju: FYI "Beggars can't be choosers" is not an insult, it is an aphorism that means that when you ask for something for free you shouldn't complain about the response you get. I'm happy to see you edited the comment you originally left under Alex's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This selector should do it...

```
$('.EventDetail tr:has(td:empty)').hide();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TgaXt/).

The [`:empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) selector looks for elements with **no** child nodes. If it is possible you may have whitespace there, but you still consider it empty, try something such as...

```
$('.EventDetail tr').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('td').filter(function() {
      return ! $.trim($(this).text());  
    }).length;
}).hide();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SqXSf/).

Comment: Thanks Alex, this did the magic, whitespace killed me. I am thankful to all the members of communities who got me in the right direction as well!